# What processor can I replace on behalf of ATMEGA328P, to get more processing power for machine learning in UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I wanted to do a machine learning project in Arduino UNO R3. But I came to know that the processor(ATMEGA328P) isn't capable of supporting the processing power needed for machine learning. So is there any other processor that is better than ATMEGA328P for machine learning that is supported in UNO? If not any other way that I can do it?

Comment: if you replace the ATMEGA328P with something else, then you no longer have an Arduino UNO

Comment: The UNO part of this question is almost certainly a dead end.  If the "it" in "If not any other way that I can do it?" refers to machine on an Arduino(ish) board, then more details on the sort of thing you want to do are needed, that "processing power" you spoke of.  You may find that none of them are really up to the task, but it depends on the task.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks a lot

Comment: @timemage Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You can't just replace the processor on the UNO with something better. The 328P is pretty much the best MCU there is in the pinout for that board.

Instead you can replace the whole UNO with something more powerful.

My board of choice for AI work would have to be one based on the Kendryte K210 chip, such as the [Maixduino](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Sipeed-Maixduino-for-RISC-V-AI-IoT-p-4046.html) (which is helpfully in an UNO footprint).  The K210 is a dual-core 64-bit 400MHz RISC-V CPU with embedded neural network co-processor. On the Maixduino it's also coupled with an ESP32 for WiFi/Bluetooth.  That's 2x 400MHz 64-bit cores, 2x 32-bit 240MHz cores, one low-power FSM core, and a neural network core all on one board.

Comment: I fully agree. Putting a machine-learning processor on an UNO shield is like strapping a get engine onto a Ford Pinto

Comment: @Majenko Thank you

Comment: @DuncanC +1 for the image of a Ford Pinto with a jet engine ... lol ... of course I added screaming passengers to that picture

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino blog recommends this: https://store.arduino.cc/nano-33-ble-sense.

See: https://blog.arduino.cc/2019/10/15/get-started-with-machine-learning-on-arduino/

I know Arduino has been talking about machine learning for about a year or so. Here's the Google search I used to find this: [Arduino machine learning](https://www.google.com/search?q=Arduino+machine+learning&oq=Arduino+machine+learning&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.9678j0j7&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8).

Here's a kit you can buy too: https://store.arduino.cc/usa/tiny-machine-learning-kit.